# Transfer 1 single random record from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server

On mssql server I try transfer single random record from one table to another

my sql script should

1. Select one random record from table called 'Test1'
2. Remove this certain record got in step 1. from table 'Test1'
3. Add this record to table 'Test2'

So far I've found

**Get one single random record from table Test1**

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    *
FROM 
    [Test1]
ORDER BY
    NEWID()
```

**Delete records where column called 'uno' is equal '1' and put deleted records in table called 'Test2'**

```
DELETE FROM
   [Test1]
OUTPUT
   deleted.*
FROM
   [Test2]
WHERE
   [uno] = '1'
```

I tried this which failed

```
DELETE I FROM (
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        [Test1]
    ORDER BY
        NEWID()
) I
OUTPUT
    deleted.*
INTO
    [Test2]
```

And this which works but transfer whole table instead of only 1 random row

```
DELETE FROM
    [Test1]
OUTPUT
    deleted.*
INTO
    [Test2]
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 
            *
        FROM 
            [Test1]
        ORDER BY
            NEWID()
    )
```

Also I tried to make adding and deleting separately
by catching result of function NEWID() in variable
and then insert and delete row with the same unique id in this way

```
DECLARE @NewReportID uniqueidentifier 
SET @NewReportID = NEWID()

INSERT INTO
   [Test2]
SELECT TOP 1
   *
FROM
   [Test1]
ORDER BY
   @NewReportID
 
GO

DELETE TOP 1 FROM
   [Test1]
ORDER BY
   @NewReportID
```

but it's failed because there is no way to use `ORDER BY` with variable

**any help would be really appreciated**

Comment: This feel like an XY Problem, if I am honest.

Comment: What are the primary key of Test1 & Test2 (if any)

Comment: there are no primary key in Test1 and Test2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT TOP 1 
    *
FROM 
    [Test1]
ORDER BY
    NEWID()
)
DELETE FROM CTE 
OUTPUT deleted.*
INTO [Test2]
```

Comment: I tried to use your solution but I've got this error



`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon. 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'. `

Comment: What version is ms-sql are you using?

Comment: Ok, my fault I added semicolon at the end of the insert statement which is before your code which I added few seconds ago and works well. Thank You very much for your help :)